# Implement delayed retry message pattern with spring cloud stream rabbit MQ binder

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-rabbit

How can I implement delay retry message pattern mentioned in this article https://jack-vanlightly.com/blog/2017/3/24/rabbitmq-delayed-retry-approaches-that-work. I don't want to loose the messages from the dead letter queue and also want retry with backoff. Once number of retries are exhausted I want the messages to be queued in DLQ.

There is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48531769/delayed-requeuing-through-rabbit-dlq/48545338#48545338) asked on stack overflow but as per the solution it will continuously retry after `dlq-ttl` expiry. Also, I do not want to loose messages from DLQ after retry attempts are exhausted.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for the functionality provided by the [RetryTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Fishtown.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#_retry_template). Is that right?

Comment: Thanks @Oleg for pointing me to `spring retry` option. It looks useful, but I have to try this out with `AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException` and `x-death` header with retry enabled `max-attempts>1`. With this combination I assume that I will not loose the messages from DLQ and will also be able to achieve retry with backoff capability.

Comment: In addition you can take a look into the Delayed Exchange, if you don't want to use Spring Retry: https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/2.0.5.RELEASE/reference/html/_reference.html#delayed-message-exchange